# Google Scripts App - Validating cell color, submitting data and saving to database

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to code where if cell color is white return False otherwise return true. when I submit the data if the cell color is other than white, save to a database as this would be considered true. However, I have been testing the validation of the color and changing the code a number of times but it doesn't seem to work. It would either accept both scenarios (cell color white or green) or doesn't save the data. If the validation is true then I get a ui.alert message "New Data Save". Any help would truly be appreciated.

```
//Validating Cell Color #00FF40 (green)
   
   var cell = "B6";
   //var colors = ["#00FF40"];
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange(cell);
   var currentColor = range.getBackground();
  if (currentColor == "#FFFFFF") {
    
    return false;
  }
  return true;
  

}
    
//Function to submit the data to Database Sheet

function SubmitData(){

  //declare a variable and set the reference of action google sheet

  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm");

  var datasheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Database");

  // to create the instance of the user-interface environment to user the alert feature

  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response=ui.alert("Submit", "Do you want to submit the data?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //checking user response
  if(response==ui.Button.NO){

  return;//to exit from this function

 }

 if(validateEntry()==true){

  var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row

  //code to update the data in the database

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B6").getValue());//Happy value in cell
  
  
  // code to update the created date and time

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,4).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm');

  // submitted by

  //datasheet.getRange(blankRow,5).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

  ui.alert('"New Data Saved ' + shUserForm.getRange("B6").getValue()+ '"');

  shUserForm.getRange("B6").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. Try `Logger.log(currentColor)` in your function `validateEntry()` (that you forgot to declare in your post :D). You'll see that is a string in lower case (`#ffffff`). So, you only need to change from:

```
if (currentColor == "#FFFFFF")
```

to:

```
if (currentColor == "#ffffff")
```

[String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#description)

Comment: Hi Ramon - I updated the code but it still does not work.

Comment: Hi Ramon - I decided to review the code again and realized an error after reviewing your suggestions. I made a couple of tweaks by adding [function validate] and changed the [function Validate Entry == true to function Validate == true] and it worked. Thanks!